# Working with Database for Magento Certification

Tags: magento-1.7, database, certification

I am preparing for magento certification exam. As per MCD guide:

1. Working with Database  13%
2. Entity Attribute Value Model  13%

both these topic covered more than 25% of exam. but I am little confused about its scope means in how much deep I will study for these topics.

Regarding Database: Magento have around 350 tables, do i need to study about these table relationship, purpose etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide here, http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram, which gives a decent overview of the Magento database. Especially the diagrams should provide you with insight to the structure.

Comment: Also http://www.magereverse.com/ can give you more information on the newer versions of Magento. The diagram died somewhere in mid 1.3 and there have been major changes since then, such as about 150 more tables.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help. http://blog.magestore.com/category/magento-certification/page/12/

Same way follow the fundamentals of magento videos as well.

For database you should know more about the tables which acts major roles in the system.

> Eg: `sales_flat_order`, `sales_flat_quote`, `sales_flat_quote_address`, `catalog_product_super_link` etc.

For EAV first of all you should have a good understanding about how magento will do operations on such attributes.

> Eg: In magento how an attribute is going to save in tables? Which tables will affect?

Note: These are examples. It's better you study thoroughly the fundamentals of magento videos as well as other resources.

Good Luck with your certification